# Sharepoint Slider Webpart not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, slider

I am new to Sharepoint and HTML coding, but I am trying to upload this slick slider (from Ken woods) html into a Sharepoint webpart. FOr some reason it works on my local machine but it does not work on an internal webpart that I'm trying to upload into. I went in to Site Assets and downloaded/up

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
     <meta charset= "UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>"
</head>
<body>

     <header>

     </header>

     <div class="your-class">
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORRImages\1.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lilu\Desktop\ORR\2.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORRImages\3.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\4.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORRImages\5.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\6.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORRImages\8.jpg" alt=""></div>
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\9.png" alt=""></div>
       <div><img src="C:\Users\lliuDesktop\ORR\10.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\11.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\12.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\13.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\14.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\15.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\16.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\17.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\ihanes\Desktop\ORR\19.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\18.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\20.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\21.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\22.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\23.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\24.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="C:\Users\lliu\Desktop\ORR\25.png" alt=""></div>
     </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
    accessibility:true,
    centerPadding:"50px",
    infinite:true,
    slidestoShow:3
  });
});
```

Comment: How does it not work? What error are you getting? What is/isn't displaying?